# Convert a .csv distance data file to nexus (.nex) file

Tags: csv, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have a pairwise distance matrix in .csv format which I wish to convert to nexus (.nex) format for analysing the data dn building trees in software that require input files in .nex format. I looked up some questions on this forum but did not get a helpful answer. Is there a straightforward way of doing this ?

Comment: .csv is format like Data1,Data2,Data3......    Data is separated by ",". It's simple , and then google the nex format.

Comment: I know both formats. I have a very large dataset so I cannot enter data manually. I was wondering if there is a way to do it using code or software.

Comment: I'm not familiar with .nex . It looks related to biological? Can you put the example transformation? Code just need know the convert rule and they can do it auto .